# Calculate the number of empty/blank fields in Power Bi

Tags: database, powerbi, analytics, dax

Hi I'm using a table which has a column Person Name followed by other columns that describes that Person i.e. Height, Age etc. The rows are filled in with the info.

However, some cells for specific people are not filled in therefore I would like to see which Person is missing details and what details are they missing as well as how many People are missing details altogether? Is there a way I can calculate/demonstrate that on Power Bi?

So essentially, count number of rows with at least one empty cell.

Comment: See if you can use `COUNTX` or `SUMX` along with `ISBLANK` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a measure like this works for me
CALCULATE(countrows(tablename) , isblank(table(columnname))